# Missing DLLs for ServiceStack

Tags: c#, dll, servicestack

I have a TestClient app based on [code taken from here](https://gist.github.com/jokecamp/4302446).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;
using ServiceStack.Common.Web;
using ServiceStack.Logging;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new JsonServiceClient(); // missing assembly reference

                client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter +=
                    delegate(HttpWebRequest request)
                    {
                        // ContentType still null at this point so we must hard code it
                        request.ContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json;
                        request.Date = DateTime.Now;

                        var secret = "5771CC06-B86D-41A6-AB39-9CA2BA338E27";
                        var token = ApiSignature.CreateToken(request, secret);
                        request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.UserId, "1");
                        request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.Signature, token);
                    };


                var teams = client.Get<List<Team>>("http://localhost:59833/api/teams");
                foreach (var team in teams)
                {
                    Label1.Text += team.Name + "<br>";
                }
            }
            catch (WebServiceException ex) // missing assembly reference
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message + " : " + ex.ResponseBody;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appear to be missing assembly references for the following:

```
JsonServiceClient
WebServiceException
```

Can anyone tell me where I can get these DLLs so that I can complete a build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing ServiceStack.Common or ServiceStack.Interfaces. Just install [ServiceStack.Common package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/) from NuGet and it will add those references correctly.

You also need this statement:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
```

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried that.  I have both `ServiceStack.Common` and ServiceStack.Interfaces` in my References folder.

Comment: @user1477388 What about ServiceStack.Text?

Comment: Indeed, I have that, too.

Comment: @user1477388 Found the problem, check my answer.

Comment: @user1477388 I added a using statement.